שְְׂרָָף... לִִשְְׁלִִישׁ וְְלִִרְְבִִיעַַ or שְְׁרָָף... לְְשָָׁלִִישׁ וּלְְרָָבִִיעַַ
As far as I am aware, s'faraddim and b'nei 'edah mizraħit (with the exception of teimanim) have שְְׁרָָף... לְְשָָׁלִִישׁ וּלְְרָָבִִיעַַ
However, the teimanim who follow nosaħ shaami (the s'faraddi-style import) nevertheless have שְְׂרָָף... לִִשְְׁלִִישׁ וְְלִִרְְבִִיעַַ
i. why is שרף being spelled here with שׁ instead of שׂ; and
ii. what has שָׁלִישׁ, the helper of a king, to do with קטורת?

Shlish here means one-third. It's a measurement.

Yes, but what is the relevance of שָׁלִישׁ; and since when has שְְׁרָָף ever been a word?

Sorry, perhaps I'm not being clear: שְְׂרָָף s'raf (spelled with שׂ sin) is tree sap/resin, but I am not familiar with any such word שְׁרָָף sh'raf (spelled with שׁ shin); and שְׁלִישׁ sh'lish (marked with sh'va na') means one-third, but שָׁלִישׁ shalish (marked with kamatz) has nothing to do with pittum k'toret... I'm looking for the source/reason for the prevalence of the latter two in Eastern communities.

I'm Ashkenazi, we say שְְׂרָָף. Either way, it refers to one of the ingredients of the incense/ketoret (specifically, apparently some sort of tree syrup, according to the phrase "הנוטף מעצי הקטף"). שליש and רביע (one-fourth) refer to the amount of ingredients prepared for the ketoret. If half were prepared, then the ketoret is valid, but the sages state that it is unknown whether a case in which a third or fourth of ingredients were prepared would still be valid.

Shalish evidently is one custom of pronouncing the word שליש. Perhaps it's incorrect, but it's become traditional, so it isn't going away. See here: https://www.ykr.org.il/question/%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2/

שְְׁרָָף Is almost certainly a typo.

Thank you for that link. And yes, @N.T., that is what I am getting at: a misprint some copyist incorporated into his edition of the siddur, and out of this a whole new variation in ritual has grown up,
